# AutoCompleteTextView with google places api

Tags: java, android, json

when i click on a road imagine "Road of new york" apears on my autoCompleteTextview with "{description=Road of new york"} any solutions ?

```
    package com.example.hp.tumg13;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class PlaceJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
    public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        JSONArray jPlaces = null;
        try {
            /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
            jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("predictions");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
         * where each json object represent a place
         */
        return getPlaces(jPlaces);
    }


    private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces){
        int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> place = null;

        /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
        for(int i=0; i<placesCount;i++){
            try {
                /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
                place = getPlace((JSONObject)jPlaces.get(i));
                placesList.add(place);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return placesList;
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace){

        HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();


        String description;

        try {

            description = jPlace.getString("description");


            place.put("description", description);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return place;
    }
}
```

I follow this tutorial : http://androidmapv2.blogspot.pt/2013/11/android-autocompletetextview-with.html

Comment: can you paste incoming json?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=123+43+Sweden&types=%28regions%29&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDcXFSC2I6ZqxQeAbUMFvJKMrA98217H9U